# Re-instantiating (updating) chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have been working with Hyperledger Fabric from sometime now. Usually, when the my chaincode instantiation fails (due to some error in the Go code) or when I just want to update it, I need to stop all the execution and then respawn CA, Orderer, CouchDB and peers. This is really problematic and time consuming.

I wish to know if there is any direct way of doing this? I am unable to find any solution online in language simple enough to understand.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if by "error in go code" you mean error in chaincode, you can install+instantiate a corrected copy with different name, or even with same name but different version and then [upgrade it](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/commands/peerchaincode.html?highlight=chaincode%20upgrade#peer-chaincode-upgrade). You don't need to stop peer or others to do either of these.